# Generate private / public SSH key with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rsa, private-key, ssh-keygen

I just need to create a private/public key pair with Python.
I want to get the same result as with the following `ssh-keygen` command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "sample.key" -N "" -f "key" && mv "key" "key.opk"
```

which generates the following:

key.opk

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

key.pub

```
ssh-rsa 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 sample.key
```

So far I have the following Python code:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
k = crypto.PKey()
k.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 4096)
print crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k)
```

output

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But I also need the public key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate SSH key pairs with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466401/how-to-generate-ssh-key-pairs-with-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did this to get the private key:

```
print crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k)
```

Do [this](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey) to get the public key:

```
print crypto.dump_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k)
```

Comment: This won't output the public key in the openssh format.

Comment: @JamesKPolk is correct - the public key generated here is not in a format which OpenSSH will accept (`key_load_public: invalid format`). I recommend [Dave Halter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39126754/10590519).

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use the [Paramiko library](http://www.paramiko.org/). Install with

> pip3 install paramiko

(or "pip install paramiko" if using python2) Consider this short example.

```
import sys
import paramiko

key = paramiko.RSAKey.generate(4096)
print(key.get_base64())  # print public key
key.write_private_key(sys.stdout)  # print private key
```