# Python equivalent of ssh-keygen command (create and sign user certificate)

Tags: python, openssh, ca, ssh-keygen

I looking for a way to get a signed openssh user certificate without using the subprocess library, equivalent to the following command:

```bash
ssh-keygen -s user_ca -I ID_USER -n user1,user2 -V+1d user-key.pub
```

Output:

```bash
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com AAAAHHNza ... user@hostname
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate SSH key pairs with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466401/how-to-generate-ssh-key-pairs-with-python)

Comment: No, because generating a private/public key pair is not the same as generating and signing a certificate. The above ssh-kegen command creates a certificate that can be used to log in over SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sshkey-tools library solves my problem